# Fast redraw of a texture after blit in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

The Kivy documentation reads so that for a rectangle with a texture created and blitted from a pixel array, like this:

```
pixels = bytearray([0x00, 0x00, 0x00] * (256 * 192))
texture = kivy.graphics.texture.Texture.create(size=(256, 192),
                                               colorfmt='rgb')
texture.blit_buffer(pixels, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
```

it can then be updated with an `ask_update()` call for whatever is the associated canvas.

The problem is that despite the `blit_buffer()` calls performs in no time, the following `ask_update()` seems to be very expensive in terms of performance, so, say, with the updating call in place FPS drops from about 8000 to 60 on my machine. To compare with Cairo, changing a `cairo.ImageSurface`'s pixel array causes redrawing the image with no additional calls and seems to perform very fast.

The question is whether there's a faster way to redraw blitted pixels in Kivy.

Comment: I suspect what's actually happening is that the ask_update isn't specifically slowing things down by a factor of 130, but rather is locking things synchronously to the actual app framerate of 60fps. If you call ask_update many times, does that make things any slower?

Comment: @inclement, yeah, that was my guess as well. Calling `ask_update()` multiple times doesn't cause slowdown, so, yes, it effectively just schedules an update. Still, the net effect is that once the canvas is marked for an update, it takes a lot of time to actually do that.